# JS Promise resolve function not working (while reject function does)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have a simple async function in my JavaScript code:

```
export default class DanceAnimationCanvas extends AnimationCanvas {

  async initTimeline(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const app = this.app;
      const timeline = new TimelineLite();

      app.loader.add(this.imageSrc).load((loader, resources) => {

        const mainImage = new PIXI.Sprite(resources[this.imageSrc].texture);
        app.stage.addChild(mainImage);

        timeline.to(mainImage, { rotation: 10, duration: 100 });

        console.log('resolve');

        resolve(timeline);

      });
    });

  }

}
```

The message 'resolve' is logged to the console, so I am sure that the resolve function is called. However, this code does not work:

```
async getCanvas(): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> {

    if (!this.timeline) {
      try {
        this.timeline = await this.initTimeline();
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log({ error });
      }
    }

    console.log('timeline', this.timeline);
   
    return this.app.view;
  }
```

This function never resolves (the HTMLCanvasElement is never returned). Also the catch function is not called, so `error` is not logged.

The weird thing is that it DOES work when I use the reject function instead of the resolve function (which is wrong, I know):

```
export default class DanceAnimationCanvas extends AnimationCanvas {

  async initTimeline(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const app = this.app;
      const timeline = new TimelineLite();

      app.loader.add(this.imageSrc).load((loader, resources) => {

        const mainImage = new PIXI.Sprite(resources[this.imageSrc].texture);
        app.stage.addChild(mainImage);

        timeline.to(mainImage, { rotation: 10, duration: 100 });

        reject(timeline);

      });
    });

  }

}
```

```
async getCanvas(): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> {

    if (!this.timeline) {
      try {
        this.timeline = await this.initTimeline();
      }
      catch (timeline) {
        this.timeline = timeline;
      }
    }

    console.log('timeline', this.timeline);
   
    return this.app.view;
  }
```

Everything now works as I would want it to, but off course this is not the right way to do it. I'm probably not seeing something, but I've been at this for an hour and just cannot see why this happens...

Comment: is app.loader.add(this.imageSrc).load method synchronous?

Comment: Any chance that `TimelineLite` has a `.then()` method?

Comment: The PIXI loader 'load' method is async. The callback function is successfully called (and the image is loaded)...

Comment: @Bergi do you mean the `timeline.to` method? No, this is synchronous and just starts an animation. The log after this method call (console.log('resolve')) is visible in the devtools console.

Comment: No, I mean `timeline.then`. Nothing else can explain what you're experiencing.

Comment: No, it doesn't have that method.